# @NotEmpty and @notNull not working during deserialization

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I have a piece of code which deserialize json string to model object,However I have provided @NotNull and @NotEmpty Validation but its not working, Below is the code:-

```
   private Student getDecryptedRequestData(String studentRequest) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    
    return  new ObjectMapper().readValue(studentRequest,Student.class);
}
```

Student.java

```
   import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
   import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

   import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

   public class Student{


    @NotEmpty
    private String studentName;

    @NotNull
    private Long roll;

   public String getStudentName() {
    return studentName;
   }

public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
    this.studentName= studentName;
}


public Long getRoll() {
    return roll;
}

public void setRoll(Long roll) {
    this.duration = roll;
}
```

}

Comment: Those are for validation and, as you noticed, aren't applied when deserialzing. If you would let spring do the marshalling (assuming you are receiving this from a web) you can use `@Valid` to validate after the object has been deserialized.

Comment: Can you tell me where I can use that @Valid here, this call is not on controller its directly in the service

Comment: How is this service called? Something is triggering this, I assumed a controller is doing this in the end. If not you need to manually do the validation, by injecting the validator and call validate.

Comment: I am decrypting a JSON String and then deserializing to a model object, so I want to validate that if the model object does not have any variable empty/null.

Comment: If you are using spring-boot and include spring-boot-configuration-processor, those annotation will be considered, if spring build an object for autowireing or configuration. But it's not used by jackson itself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used below code and it worked and added @JsonCreator in the constructor of POJO

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_CREATOR_PROPERTIES, true);
```

Answer (score -1):

before you return Student you can use

```
Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator().validate(Student);
```

or use component

```
 @Component
@Slf4j
public class ValidatorUtils {
    private final ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    private final Validator validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();

    public <T> void checkValid(T object, Class<?>... groups) {
        Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> set = validator.validate(object, groups);
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(set)) {
            throw new ConstraintViolationException(set);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add some supporting information to your answer and use the code tools for formatting your code.